# Android change variable value

Tags: android, web-services, variables, fragment

I have an Android script inside a Fragment in which you have two buttons: platillos, bebidas, if you choose "platillos" then the variable "tipo" changes to "alimento" and send it to a web service to then display all the food of the menu, and the same with the "bebidas" button.

I dont know what is happening but the variable stays always the same with the same value of the first button I click.

**Here is my code:**

```
    package com.limecream.myday;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import net.gotev.uploadservice.MultipartUploadRequest;
import net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadNotificationConfig;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.UUID;

public class menuesFragmento extends Fragment{

    //variables
    String imagenMenu;
    String imagenesMenu[];
    String tituloMenu;
    String titulosMenu[];
    String descripcionMenu;
    String descripcionesMenu[];
    String precioMenu;
    String preciosMenu[];
    int Mostrar;
    LinearLayout contMenu;
    TextView platillosBoton;
    TextView bebidasBoton;
    String tipo;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menues_fragmento, container, false);

        contMenu = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.ContMenu);

        platillosBoton = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.platillosBoton);
        bebidasBoton = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bebidasBoton);

        bebidasBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tipo = "bebida";
                menu();
            }
        });

        platillosBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tipo = "alimento";
                menu();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void menu(){
        //sacar el total de array
        try{
            httpHandler handler = new httpHandler();
            String response = handler.post(variablesApp.url + "MyDayFiles/noticias.php?tipo=" + tipo);
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
            Mostrar = array.length();
            if(Mostrar > 5){
                Mostrar = 5;
            }
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //sacar el total de array

        int arrayNoticias = Mostrar;

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayNoticias; i ++){
            RelativeLayout rlProductos = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
            rlProductos.setId(+1);
            rlProductos.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
            rlProductos.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textviews_menu);
            contMenu.addView(rlProductos);

            try {
                httpHandler handler = new httpHandler();
                String response = handler.post(variablesApp.url + "MyDayFiles/menu.php?tipo=" + tipo);
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                for(int u = 0; u<array.length(); u++){
                    JSONObject json_obj = array.getJSONObject(u);
                    tituloMenu += json_obj.getString("titulo") + "/";
                    tituloMenu = tituloMenu.replace("null", "");
                    titulosMenu = tituloMenu.split("/");

                    descripcionMenu += json_obj.getString("descripcion") + "/";
                    descripcionMenu = descripcionMenu.replace("null", "");
                    descripcionesMenu = descripcionMenu.split("/");

                    precioMenu += json_obj.getString("precio") + "/";
                    precioMenu = precioMenu.replace("null", "");
                    preciosMenu = precioMenu.split("/");

                    imagenMenu += json_obj.getString("imagen") + "/";
                    imagenMenu = imagenMenu.replace("null", "");
                    imagenesMenu = imagenMenu.split("/");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //imagen
            ImageView imagenPlatillo = new ImageView(getActivity());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsImagenPlatillos = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
            paramsImagenPlatillos.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            paramsImagenPlatillos.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            paramsImagenPlatillos.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
            imagenPlatillo.setLayoutParams(paramsImagenPlatillos);
            imagenPlatillo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imagenPlatillo.setId(+2);
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(variablesApp.url + "MyDayFiles/uplimages/" + imagenesMenu[i]).into(imagenPlatillo);
            //imagen

            //textview titulo
            TextView textViewTitulo = new TextView(getActivity());
            textViewTitulo.setId(+3);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsTVTitulo = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            paramsTVTitulo.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, imagenPlatillo.getId());
            textViewTitulo.setLayoutParams(paramsTVTitulo);
            textViewTitulo.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
            textViewTitulo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            textViewTitulo.setTextSize(12);
            textViewTitulo.setText(titulosMenu[i]);

            //textview descripcion
            TextView textViewDesc = new TextView(getActivity());
            textViewDesc.setId(+4);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsTVPDesc = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            paramsTVPDesc.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textViewTitulo.getId());
            paramsTVPDesc.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, imagenPlatillo.getId());
            textViewDesc.setLayoutParams(paramsTVPDesc);
            textViewDesc.setTextSize(12);
            textViewDesc.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
            textViewDesc.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
            textViewDesc.setText(descripcionesMenu[i]);

            //textview precio
            TextView textViewPrecio = new TextView(getActivity());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsTVPrecio = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            paramsTVPrecio.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            textViewPrecio.setLayoutParams(paramsTVPrecio);
            textViewPrecio.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            textViewPrecio.setTextSize(12);
            textViewPrecio.setText(preciosMenu[i]);

            //agregar los textview al relativelayout
            rlProductos.addView(textViewTitulo);
            rlProductos.addView(textViewDesc);
            rlProductos.addView(imagenPlatillo);
            rlProductos.addView(textViewPrecio);

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: are you getting any error logs?

Comment: @Jimit Patel no, it just does not update the variable, it stays with the first value selected

Comment: If I were you I would have done API call on background thread using volley or retrofit. And the result from background thread would have published to my UI. You can check this out https://github.com/Android-Workshop/Network-Volley-Example